# Scala UDF -- Combine column values in a specific formatting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

DF1 is what I have now, and I want make DF1 looks like DF2.

Desired Output:

```
 DF1                                                           DF2
+---------+----------------------------------------+          +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   ID    |         Category                       |          |   ID    |                  category_name                                    |
+---------+----------------------------------------+          +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+  
|  31898  |   CP Bill Payment                      |          |  31898  |  CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer + CP IMT (CPS Limit + CPS Payee) |  
|  31898  |   CP e-Transfer + CP IMT               |          |  32614  |  CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer + CP Other Transfer (CPS Blocked)|
|  31898  |   CPS Limit + CPS Payee                |          |  35431  |  CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer                                  |
|  32614  |   CP e-Transfer + CP Other Transfer    |          |  33987  |  CP IMT (CPS Limit)                                               |
|  32614  |   CP Bill Payment                      |  =====>  |  35672  |  CPS Blocked                                                      |
|  32614  |   CPS Blocked                          |  =====>  |  37612  |  CPS Blocked + CPS Stop/Cancel/Reverse                            |
|  35431  |   CP e-Transfer                        |          +---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  35431  |   CP Bill Payment                      |
|  33987  |   CP IMT                               |
|  33987  |   CPS Limit                            |
|  35672  |   CPS Blocked                          |
|  37612  |   CPS Blocked + CPS Stop/Cancel/Reverse|
+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

I have the code below:

```
val DF2 = DF1.groupBy("ID").agg(collect_set("Category").as("CategorySet"))
.groupBy("ID")
.agg(collect_set("Category").as("CategorySet"))
.withColumn( "category_name",
  when(array_contains($"CategorySet", "CP Bill Payment") && array_contains($"CategorySet", "CP e-Transfer + CP IMT") && array_contains($"CategorySet", "CPS Limit + CPS Payee"), "CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer + CP IMT (CPS Limit + CPS Payee)").otherwise("---other conditions---"))
.select("ID","category_name")
```

Logic is that for the same ID, 31898/32614/33987: if contains CP* and CPS*, it should be CP* (CPS*) or CP* + CP* (CPS*); 35431: if no CPS* in the array, just use + to concatenate all elements in the array; 35672/37612: otherwise, just the element in the array. BTW, the Category should be sorted by ascending order.

The code is working, it's just too many possible combinations. How to use UDF to do the same thing? Or is there any built-in function could do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can create several UDAFs to contain the logic you need.

Comment: could you give me some example? not too familiar with scala udf

Comment: Is your ID a String type?

Comment: it's decimal (28,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can think for now:

```
//UDF
def mapColumn(col: String) = udf { (xs: Seq[String]) => 
                        xs.map { x => 
                          if (x.contains(col+" ")) x else null
                        }.filter(_ != null).mkString(" + ")
                     }

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.groupBy("Id").agg(
                               mapColumn("CP")(sort_array(collect_set("Category"))).as("CategorySetCP"),
                               mapColumn("CPS")(sort_array(collect_set("Category"))).as("CategorySetCPS")
                               ).withColumn("CategorySetCPS_New",concat(lit(" ("),'CategorySetCPS,lit(")")))
                               .withColumn("category_name",
                                           when(length($"CategorySetCP") > 0 and length($"CategorySetCPS") > 0,concat($"CategorySetCP",$"CategorySetCPS_New")).
                                           otherwise(when(length($"CategorySetCP") >0 and length($"CategorySetCPS") === 0,$"CategorySetCP").
                                           otherwise($"CategorySetCPS"))
                                           )
           .select('Id,'category_name)

df1.show(false)
```

Ouput:

```
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|Id   |category_name                                                    |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|33987|CP IMT (CPS Limit)                                               |
|32614|CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer + CP Other Transfer (CPS Blocked)|
|35672|CPS Blocked                                                      |
|35431|CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer                                  |
|31898|CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer + CP IMT (CPS Limit + CPS Payee) |
|35612|CPS Blocked + CPS Stop/Cancel/Reverse                            |
+-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how to use UDAFs. Obviously, you don´t need an UDAF to concatenate columns values by id, but it allows to add more logic. For example, to concatenate the values by the ID field you can create a UDAF like:

```
class ConcatenateStrings extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  override def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("input", StringType) :: Nil)

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("pair", StringType) :: Nil)

  override def dataType: DataType = StringType

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = buffer(0) = ""

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
      val b = buffer.getAs[String](0)
      val i = input.getAs[String](0)
      buffer(0) = { if(b.isEmpty) b + i else b + " + " + i }
  }

  override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    val b1 = buffer1.getAs[String](0)
    val b2 = buffer2.getAs[String](0)
    if(!b1.isEmpty)
      buffer1(0) = (b1) ++ " + " ++ (b2)
    else
      buffer1(0) = b2
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    val yourString = buffer.getAs[String](0)
    // Compute your logic and return another String
    yourString + "@procesed"
  }
}
```

Then you can include in your aggregation call:

```
object testAppl0 {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val agg0 = new ConcatenateStrings()

    implicit val spark: SparkSession =
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Test")
        .master("local[1]")
        .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val rows = Seq(Row(31898,"CP Bill Payment"), Row(31898,"CP e-Transfer + CP IMT"), Row(31898,"CPS Limit + CPS Payee "))

    val schema = List(
      StructField("ID", IntegerType, true),
      StructField("Category", StringType, true))

    val df =  spark.createDataFrame(
      spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows),
      StructType(schema)
    )

    df.groupBy("ID").agg(agg0($"Category")).show(false)

  }
}
```

It will return a new column "concatenatestrings(Category)":

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID   |concatenatestrings(Category)                                              |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|31898|CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer + CP IMT + CPS Limit + CPS Payee @procesed|
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Check this, maybe it can help

Comment: Thanks! But the logic is to put any string has CPS in a bracket; So any string has CP in the front is the main category, and any string has CPS in the front is sub category. In your example, it should be this:  CP Bill Payment + CP e-Transfer + CP IMT (CPS Limit + CPS Payee). @EmiCareOfCell44

Comment: Could you give me an example that could work with the DataFrame in my question? that would be really helpful! thank you so much @EmiCareOfCell44

Comment: So maybe UDAF is not necessary, just need a function to look up strings have CPS is the front to put in a bracket () after the strings have CP in the front, and concatenate strings have CP in front with + sign @EmiCareOfCell44

Comment: Maybe, it depends of your logic. With UDAFs you can create much more complex logic, but if it is so simple they are not necessary.

Comment: How to do this using a function? Could you give me an example that could work with the DataFrame in my question? @ EmiCareOfCell44